# jest redux-thunk test if action of same module is dispatched

Tags: unit-testing, redux, flux, redux-thunk, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for a redux action creator that dispatches another action which is defined in the same file. It's hard to explain, so here's an example:

```
// actions/timer.js

export const onClickButton = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    // ... do something
    dispatch(someAction);
    dispatch(onTimerStart()); // This is the action creator stated below
  };
};

export const onTimerStart = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    // ... do something
    dispatch(someAction);
  };
};
```

I'm using jest and I want to make sure the `onTimerStart` action is dispatched when calling `onClickButton`. (In my actual code these action creators take some arguments and based on those, `onTimerStart` should or should not be dispatched)

I can't seem to figure out how to mock `onTimerStart` so I can test if it's called or not.

Comment: Hi @Bram : Iam also having similar issues, have you found a solution to your problem?If yes, kindly share the result

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mocking onTimerStart(), you could use "[redux-mock-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store)" and assert that your expected actions have been dispatched.

Here's a rough example.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as timerActions from './actions/timerActions';
import * as types from './constants/actionTypes';
import { InitialAppState } from './reducers/initialState';

const createMockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

describe('timerActions', () => {

    it('successful call should dispatch someAction', () => {

        // Arrange.
        const expectedActions = [
            { type: types.someAction},
        ];

        const store = createMockStore(InitialAppState);

        // Act.
        store.dispatch(actions.onClickButton());

        // Assert.
        const dispatchedActions = store.getActions();
        expect(dispatchedActions).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });

});
```

Using this example, you will just need to add in the arguments you have mentioned, and import your actionCreators, actionTypes and initialState from the correct location.

Note that this example was written in typescript.

Comment: Hi NIck, thanks for the example. Your example works if there is one dispatch. However, when there are multiple dispatches, the assertion always takes the last dispatch so I am trying to figure out how to test multiple dispatches in the same actions. I can't cleanly post code in the comments, but to give you an example from the original question, the second action 'onTimerStart' is a single dispatch (which works) while 'onClickButton' has two dispatches and jest catches only the second one.

Comment: @AndriyKulak, It sounds like you're trying to test async actions. See the redux docs for how to do this - http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a mock for the dispatch using `jest.fn()`.
2. Then, call the action creator once to get the "thunk" (the returned function that takes dispatch as an argument).
3. With that, call that returned function with your mock dispatch as the argument.
4. You can see the calls to dispatch using dispatch.mock.calls.

**(1) Mock Function**

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();
```

**(2) (3) Get the thunk and call it**

```
const thunk = onClickButton();
thunk(dispatch);
```

**(4) Check the calls to dispatch**

```
// indices mean: [the second call] [the first argument of that call]
dispatch.mock.calls[1][0]
```